# Spring Cloud Dataflow scriptable-transform fails for python language

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Recently, I download the 1.7.0 release and tried to deploy the following

```
stream create amqp-to-hdfs --definition "mqtt-source-rabbit
--username=admin --password=pwd --url=/path/to/host--topics=dmj/ccs/sms/stream |
scriptable-transform --language=python --script='return \"payload\"' |
hdfs --fs-uri=hdfs://path/to/hdfs:9000 --directory=/path/to/recording --file-name=ingest"
```

However, this failed to start due to the following issue:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.scriptable.transform.processor.ScriptableTransformProcessorConfiguration': 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transformer' defined in
org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.scriptable.transform.processor.ScriptableTransformProcessorConfiguration: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.script.ScriptEngineManager is
unable to create a script engine for language 'python'
```

This is odd because I do have python installed and if I change the language and script values to ruby-based code, everything works.  However, I need to use Python for this task.

Any ideas

Comment: What version of the `scriptable-transform` app did you register in this case? Do you have `org.python.jython-standalone`  in your classpath? The `PyScriptEngineFactory` from `org.python.jython-standalone` is expected to be used by the `ScriptEngineManager` when creating the script engine for `python`.

Answer (score 0):

The scriptable transformer will require you to have function declared and you will call that function at the end of the function defination

```
def myFunction(firstVar, lastVar):
    return firstVar +" some addition "+ lastVar;
myFunction("First ", " Second ")
```